# Communication between two Angular 1 components

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, components

I have a table component that displays at table, and a print component that displays the same table in a format ready for printing. Both reside in the same HTML page.

The print component needs some information from the table component. This information is useless to the outside controller, it just needs to get from one component to the other.

The obvious solution was to output-bind a `printInfo` object to the table component, and input-bind it to the print component, like so:

```
<table-component ... on-print-info-changed="vm.onPrintInfoChanged(info)"/>
<print-component print-info="vm.printInfo"/>
```

I set `printInfo` in `onPrintInfoChanged`.

while this works, it doesn't seem right. Since both components already rely on each other, I'd much rather do something like this:

```
<table-component .../>
<print-component table="<ref to table-component>"/>
```

That way the controllers doesn't need to know anything about the dependency between the two components, except that there is one.

The question is - how do I supply the reference to the table component? I can get the table controller's element on the page, but how do I get the component's controller from it?

I found some old (and sometimes contradicting) answers, but they were all relevant to old versions of Angular, before anybody used components or ES 6.

Comment: Would all be solved by storing all the data and methods in a service and sharing the service. Not clear what *"needs some info"* really means

Comment: what you are doing is completely correct... Very similar old example is accordion directive... accordion has main directive (which should refer your page controller) and it has also header and content directives inside. so whenever header is clicked main component controller function is triggered and it make content directive be aware of that so it should open... So basically you could have one main component on top of two if you do not want to use your page controller...

Comment: @charlietfl, I don't want to store the data in a service. A service is inherently a singleton, while I can have multiple pairs throughout the application. The kind of information they share is not relevant to the question, they need to share information (it's the user's selection of filters and column orders, but again - irrelevant)

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz, I can't have one component encapsulate both of them, as both can appear in different regions of the page - depending on the user code.

Comment: service can still have multiple sets of data, just need a key to match  each set. Would be much easier to help with a [mcve]